# Does setting a kinesis shard-iterator-type to LATEST risk losing messages in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

We are trying to determine the best `shard-iterator-type` for our lambda but I'm getting mixed information about the functionality of the shard iterator type **AFTER** a lambda has been deployed for the first time.

I have been told that if we use a `shard-iterator-type` of `LATEST` that when we go to deploy a updated version of the lambda we will loose messages since the lambda will just always pull the most recent messages from kinesis and will ignore the ones it didn't process while it was being deployed.

My question is: is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

When your app starts reading with `LATEST` iterator type it will start reading from the next record coming. So all the data that has already been in the queue will be ignored. Which means that if your app has a downtime - every message during that downtime will be skipped.

You can overcome this by saving the sequence number of the latest message your app read and then using `AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` iterator type and provide the saved sequence number. It's like a checkpoint.

If your lambda deployed for the first time(no previous sequence number saved) you probably want to start with either:

- `TRIM_HORIZON` - start by reading the oldest data in the queue. Might be a bit too much if you have a lot of data and a long retention period
- `LATEST` - start reading from the next incoming message

Comment: So when using `Latest` with a lambda it doesn't store the last message you processed but `Trim_Horizion` does store the last message?

Comment: No, not really. Trim_Horizon will always start with the oldest message you have in the queue(Horizon). If you want toa checkpoint you'll need to make sure that the lambda stores sequence_number somewhere before shutting down, and the next one starts should read that. You might use a DB or an S3 file for storage